# Is there a word for phrasing something as a question?

Tags: questions, phrasing

Ex: Bathroom -> Bathroom?

I know there is one, I just don't remember the word for it

Comment: Can you give more examples and how the word you're looking for is used? Do you mean "upspeak"?

Answer (score 3):

[**Interrogative**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/interrogative):

> **1 a** : used in a question
> **b** : having the form or force of a question
>
> “Did you go to school today?” is an *interrogative* sentence.